# MVC how to read only user specific records from database uploaded with a relational foreign key

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a scenario in MVC where I allow users to uplaod a excel file, the data gets written to a database which has a relational table(foregin key) to another table. Table A has all the records with foregih key to Table B. Users can simultanealy uplaod records to the database, how can I get only the recors that specific user ihas uplaoded to database, I have tried the below code but it return all the recorsd in the database. PLease help.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {

        List<CleanSupplierClaim> supplierClaimsData = new List<CleanSupplierClaim>();

        try
        {
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {


                string path = file.FileName;

                Excel.Application application = new Excel.Application();
                Excel.Workbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(path);
                Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
                Excel.Range range = worksheet.UsedRange;


                for (int row = 5; row < range.Rows.Count; row++)
                {
                    CleanSupplierClaim supplierList = new CleanSupplierClaim();

                    supplierList.Action = ((Excel.Range)range.Cells[row, 1]).Text;


                    supplierList.Line_Number = ((Excel.Range)range.Cells[row, 2]).Text;
                    supplierList.Total_Claim = Decimal.Parse(((Excel.Range)range.Cells[row, 3]).Text);
                    supplierList.Currency = ((Excel.Range)range.Cells[row, 4]).Text;
                    supplierList.ClaimReference = ((Excel.Range)range.Cells[row, 5]).Text;

                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(supplierList.Action) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(supplierList.Line_Number) && supplierList.Total_Claim == null && String.IsNullOrEmpty(supplierList.Currency))
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    supplierClaimsData.Add(supplierList);

                }

                //Here I write to the foregin key table and then read thag ID to save it to all my records as a relationship id
                var cleanGPSessionObject = new CleanSupplierClaimsUploadSession { Date_Created = DateTime.Now };

                db.CleanSupplierClaimsUploadSessions.Add(cleanGPSessionObject);
                db.SaveChanges();

                var sessionID = cleanGPSessionObject.Id;

                //Here I write all the records includin the ID I got from the foreign key table
                foreach (var claim in supplierClaimsData)
                {
                    db.CleanSupplierClaims.Add(new CleanSupplierClaim
                           {
                               Id = claim.Id,
                               ST_Key = claim.ST_Key,
                               Action = claim.Action,
                               ClaimReference = claim.ClaimReference,
                               Currency = claim.Currency,
                               Line_Number = claim.Line_Number,
                               Total_Claim = claim.Total_Claim,
                               Domain_Username = claim.Domain_Username,
                               DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
                               ImportFlag = false,
                               ReadyForImport = false,
                               CleanSupplierClaimsUploadSessionID = sessionID//Foreging key
                           });
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }


            }
        }
        catch (FileLoadException ex)
        {
            ViewData["error"] = ex.Message;
        }



        TempData["supplierClaimsData"] = supplierClaimsData;

        //Here I attempt to read the recorsds I just wrote with the iD
        var claimsRecords = db.CleanSupplierClaims.Include(c => c.CleanSupplierClaimsUploadSession);
        //return RedirectToAction("ValidateClaims", "Home", supplierClaimsData);
        return View("Index", claimsRecords.ToList());
    }

    public ActionResult ValidateClaims()
    {
        var claimsRecords = db.CleanSupplierClaims.Include(c => c.CleanSupplierClaimsUploadSession);

        List<CleanSupplierClaim> supplierClaimsData = claimsRecords.ToList();// My issue is here, I get all records and not the ones the user just uploaded

        CleanSupplierClaimData supplierClaimUplaod = new CleanSupplierClaimData();
```

The main problem is that I get all records and I just need the ones the user just uploaded using the foreign key, is there perhaps a better more sophisticated way to do this. your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you store the excel on a person somehow? if not then its impossible

Comment: No, I am using a session table, which is the relationship to the actual records. How can I achieve this?

Comment: uum sessions are destroyed between each session. so if you restart your browser then the csession information is gone for ever. you need to add userId to the `CleanSupplierClaim`

Comment: I will try using user ID, how do I handle it if the same user has multiple uploads one after the other?

Comment: Read up on one to many relation. litterally just google "one to many"